# Failed to login/wait message and redirect html/css/ajax

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using simple login page(html/css/ajax) to log into the user.
I have a few things that I want to make, and would appreciate inputs.

1)How do you make a failed to login message if unauthorized? I want to make it just say unauthorized, instead of a hard pop up.

2)Same thing for wait message. How do I alert the user to wait 5 seconds or so before redirecting(I want message to popup as well preferably)?
I am using window.location = url as redirect as soon as user logs in.
Also, is there a way to hide the window.location from the users when in production?

And a simple html page with username/password.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function(){
                     $.ajax({
                            type: "Post",
                            url: $('form').attr('action'),
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                            window.location = 'http://login/user/login/';
                            }
                            });
                                          return false;
                     });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code - there are many different ways this could be done.

Comment: @user2182349 posted. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

1) probably you want inject html

2) for waiting you can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function. And second part, you can not hide javascript functions because they are running at client side and client need download source code for run.

EDIT:

simply you can do via [HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
    }, 2000);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c7zLe5xq/)

EDIT 2:
html

```
<p id="my-message-for-login">my login message</p>
```

javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: $('form').attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        if(result == 'isLoggedSuccessfuly') {
            $("#my-message-for-login").text("You are logged and you will be redirected in 2 seconds");
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = '/you/are/logged/page';
            }, 2000);
        }
        else {
            $("#my-message-for-login").text("Something wrong! You are NOT logged");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. I did setTimeout but can you show an example for injecting html for failed login msg and wait message?

Comment: What is this HTML DOM for though? Is this for message? It just says to click, and it'll change, but is that a wait message or failure?

Comment: what you want? user login you want show message and redirect him after 5s?

Comment: Ah ok where is the link address tho? Would you be able to modify this into my code posted above? Also user would submit login button. This message would show automatically and redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple login form

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
<h1>Login</h1>
<p id="login-error-message" class="error" style="display:none">Please enter a username and password</p>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
<button id="login-btn">Login</button>
</div>
```

You could use this jQuery code:

```
$("#login-btn").on("click", function (evt) {
    $("#login-error-message").hide();
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "auth.php",
        data: {
            "username": $("#username").val(),
                "password": $("#password").val()
        }
    }).done(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
        if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.href = "index.php";
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
    $("#login-error-message").show();
});
```

If the credentials are accepted by the server it could return a 200 or 204, then wait five seconds and redirect.

If it doesn't redirect, it will show the login error message.